# Can't locate File/Remote.pm in @INC (@INC contains:

Tags: linux, perl, centos, perl-module

I'm having trouble with the following.

> Can't locate File/Remote.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8/CPANPLUS/Shell/Default/Plugins
>   /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
>   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
>   /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .)

If I list the flowing the file is actually there :

```
 ls /pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8/CPANPLUS/Shell/Default/Plugins
Diff.pm  HOWTO.pod  Remote.pm  RT.pm  Source.pm
```

I'm really stuck here, this script was running on Solaris, to cut down on licenses I've converted 100+ sites to centos, and this script is required to run on a few, but I can't quite get over this step with google alone.

Comment: Please don't edit your post into a completely new question after you've gotten answers. It invalidates the work people have done writing their answers and makes things confusing for future visitors, since some answers will address the original question and some will address the new question. Instead, post a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That file is for [CPANPLUS::Shell::Default::Plugins::Remote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPANPLUS::Shell::Default::Plugins::Remote)<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

`@INC` contains

- `/pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8/CPANPLUS/Shell/Default/Plugins`
- `/usr/local/lib64/perl5`
- `/usr/local/share/perl5`
- `/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl`
- `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl`
- `/usr/lib64/perl5`
- `/usr/share/perl5`
- `.`

so Perl checks for

- `/pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8/CPANPLUS/Shell/Default/Plugins/File/Remote.pm`
- `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/File/Remote.pm`
- `/usr/local/share/perl5/File/Remote.pm`
- `/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Remote.pm`
- `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Remote.pm`
- `/usr/lib64/perl5/File/Remote.pm`
- `/usr/share/perl5/File/Remote.pm`
- `./File/Remote.pm`

The module isn't installed (or it's installed in a directory into which Perl hasn't been told to look). Simply install the module (by using `cpan File::Remote`).

---

1. This brings up a second problem: `use CPANPLUS::Shell::Default::Plugins::Remote;` won't work because

   ```
   /pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8
   ```

   should have been added to `@INC` instead of

   ```
   /pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8/CPANPLUS/Shell/Default/Plugins
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work, as you've explained above.  

The following is set:
    /pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8

 
Still getting : Can't locate Plugins/Remote.pm in @INC .... 

so I tried cpan File::Remote

     [root File]# cpan  File::Remote
     CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
     Running install for module 'File::Remote'
     /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr

Comment: That's an unrelated problem.  It's probably caused by a bad value in `@INC`. (I think you have two builds of Perl, and you are trying to access the modules installed by one when using the other.) The bad value is probably supplied via the `PERL5LIB` env var, so clearing that var should do the trick.

Comment: uncommented it, and it ran, however, it put it in /usr/local/share/perl5/File instead, can I copy this over to the other directory?

Comment: Don't move or copy any files. Don't change `@INC` (except to remove the stuff you added). Just clear PERL5LIB (permanently) and run `cpan File::Remote`

Comment: I got it, had to disable the env var, install it, and reenable it. It works now, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2):

`Remote.pm` is there but `File/Remote.pm` is not.

Either it isn't the right file, or you need to create the `File` directory and move it inside.

ikegami's comment, which looks to be correct, makes this the former. It is the wrong Remote.pm.

You need to install [the correct module](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Remote) properly (e.g. with [cpan minus](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Menlo/script/cpanm-menlo)).

Comment: Ahhhh, Thank you, I'll try this! :)

Comment: Don't move that file! It's for CPANPLUS::Shell::Default::Plugins::Remote.

Comment: @BenCoughlan You can't copy the source of [CPANPLUS::Shell::Default::Plugins::Remote](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPANPLUS::Shell::Default::Plugins::Remote) into a directory named `File` and expect it to magically become the source for [File::Remote](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Remote). They're totally different modules that do different things; your code may be able to load the module, but it won't work beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

---

```
# cpan
> cpan install File::Remote
```

http://search.cpan.org/~nwiger/File-Remote-1.17/Remote.pm

---

Comment: Running install for module 'File::Remote'
 /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /pkg/qct/software/perl/q4_06/.lib/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr
 [root File]#